# How do I find at least the closest penetrating point with SAT?

Tags: collision-detection, physics, collision-resolution, separating-axis-theorem

For more accurate simulations, I want to find the closest point of another polygon to one polygon's center when they collide. Is this possible with the SAT algorithm? Is it a good strategy at all for semi-accurate physics simulations (more accurate than the normal between the 2 polygons' centers)?

Comment: It sounds like you meant to ask [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26888/finding-the-contact-point-with-sat?rq=1). The closest point to another polygon's center [doesn't sound right to me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hvs7t.png).

Comment: Thanks! I managed to do something with the minimum translation vector. Btw, thanks for the answer to the other question. It was a lot of help.